# Scroll-based animations: how to create them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

I've come across this webpage: http://www.wsj.com/ad/cocainenomics

It shows exactly the kind of animations I would like to learn to create.

Nothing massively complex, just elements or layers coming in while the user scrolls the page (don't consider the 'powder' animation on hero visual).

What technique / programming language / `js-based library` would you expert animators advice as the best option to achieve this?

I'm considering:

- pure jQuery animations
- jQuery triggered `css3` animations
- a `velocity.js-based` approach with minimal `jQuery` use only for chaining an animation call onto a `jQuery` element object

What approach between these you guys deem to be preferable? Or do you have something else in mind?

Do you think that the mighty power of `velocity.js` is disproportionate for animations this simple? I've seen velocity demos and they are way more complex than the `scroll-based` animations the above website includes.

Comment: You can use Textillate.js https://jschr.github.io/textillate/ for text  and wow.js for scroll based animation http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/ bith plugin are pretty good and provide range of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found success with [Skrollr](https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) before for this sort of thing:

- Check out the demo at https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/
- Look at the code at https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

EDIT: I've just looked at the Skrollr docs and noticed it stopped being maintained about a year ago. A quick Google brought up [ScrollMagic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/) as a possible alternative. I'd also recommend digging into the source code of the example site you provided, and seeing if you can get an insight into what they've used!

[Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) isn't necessarily something you'd go to specifically for the kind of scroll-position-based animations you're looking for - it's just an alternative option for doing the same as you'd do with jQuery's `animate()` but with behind-the-scenes magic to make the animations more efficient.

Strictly speaking, StackOverflow probably isn't the best place for this type of question (see the guidelines for questions over at https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) - so your question might get flagged by moderators!

Answer (score 0):

please check this, https://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/ i believe its exactly what you are looking for, check the demo here : https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/index.html
i believe its a pretty simple option, since its free and its fully customizable.
(also its almost only css with a little jquery)